# In vee-validate,how can i validate part of form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

My English is not very well.When I use 'this.$validator.validate()',I don't want to validate all inputs in page.How can I validate some of them?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use [scopes](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/scopes.html).

For each input you want to validate, add the attribute `data-vv-scope="group1"` then you can do `this.$validator.validate('group1.*')`.

If the fields are all in the same form, you can just apply the scope to that form and it will still work.